# Repetitive gsap animation code and server load time

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, load, gsap

I'm animating some elements that has a lot of common animation so i think it's very repetitive and it uses extra code

```
TweenLite.from('.port', 5, {
     opacity: 0,
     rotation: 180,
     marginLeft: '50vw',
     ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7)
});
TweenLite.from('.folio', 5, {
     opacity: 0,
     rotation: 180,
     marginRight: '-50vw',
     ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7)
});
```

the code above the only difference is the margin so is it better to make my code more clean and light to do something like that :

```
TweenLite.from('.port, .folio', 5, {
     opacity: 0,
     rotation: 180,
     marginLeft: '50vw',
     ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7)
});
TweenLite.from('.folio', 5, {
     marginRight: '-50vw'
});
```

or what do you guy think in this case, i wanna make my code more light and clean since they have everything in common except the margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible as you did it, assuming that the behavior in [this demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/rNBmyVK?editors=0010) is what you're wanting.

Otherwise you could use a generic vars object and pass that into your tweens, using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add values. [Demo of that here](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/rNBmyVK?editors=0010).

```
var vars = {
  opacity: 0,
  rotation: 180,
  marginLeft: '50vw',
  ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7)
};

TweenLite.from('.port', 5, vars);

TweenLite.from('.folio', 5, Object.assign({
  marginRight: '-50vw'
}, vars));
```

The next version of GSAP (yet to be released) will make what you're trying to do here even easier!

P.S. You're more likely to get help more quickly over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) for these types of questions.

Comment: Thank you zach that was really helpful